# how to create this kind of layout in flutter android development?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[This is a setting page how to make this kind of layout?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5inEc.jpg)

Comment: Bring out more details in your query. If possible, share your code. Do you want the header to stay still while the rest of it to scroll?

Comment: yes header to stay still and all part scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomScrollView to achieve it.

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
   SliverPersistentHeader(
     pinned: true,  
     delegate: ...
   ),
   SliverList(...) 
  ]
)
```